# java convert literals to objects

Tags: java

I have an app where a property file contains data in the following format

```
name=abc#$#String
age=23#$#Integer
```

When the value is casted, cast it to values after #$#. is it possible to do this without using a switch or if then else statement.

What I would like to do is have a way to convert the string String or Integer to objects and be able to cast the value without using an if then else block. Something of this sort

```
String[] tmp = props.getProperty("name").split("#$#");
String name = (tmp[1])tmp[0];
```

Comment: Why isn't the entry simply name=abc and age=23?

Comment: Your code-snippet doesn't quite make sense to me: if you know enough to write `String name`, then you must already know that it's going to be a `String`, so there's no need for the `(tmp[1])` notation. No?

Comment: You can't use a variable as a cast specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't cast a String object to an Integer object; String is not a subclass of Integer. You can, however, convert a String literal into an object and cast something to it:

```
Class.forName("some.package.name.SomeClass").cast(aSubclass);
```

However, the above still applies. You won't be able to cast "23", a String, into an Integer.

It looks like you're over thinking this a bit. This could be as simple as an if else statement, or perhaps a Factory method, which would eventually do the same thing anyways.

Also, I would assume that you know the object type before hand, as you're not going to map *name* to an Integer in the first place. In which case, you might as well do what alexandros said.

Comment: I guess i am not very good and describing my problem but Class.forName("some.package.name.SomeClass").cast(aSubclass); should help me fix my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question.
First, I think that using split method make things more complicated. Since you know that your values contain #$# you can just replace them with an empty string.
Second, since you know (I assume) that in your property file you have a property called name and has type String and a property age that is integer you can do the following (no if else check needed)

```
    String name = props.getProperty("name").replace("$#$", "");
    Integer age = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("age").replace("$#$", ""));
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: i was just making the example simple. The code has no knowledge of the contents of the property file. it receives a insert query and the columns and values from the property file. The code iterates through list of properties casts it and then insert it into the db. i can use something like if ("String") then (String)name else if ("Integer") then .....I am wonder if I can avoid it and somehow using reflection or something else cast a value

Comment: I am sorry, still don't get it. The code iterates through a list of properties and then what?
When you iterate the property file you have key and value. How do you decide that the value is String or Integer?